# Error Py4JJavaError al crear sesión de spark

Tags: jupyter, spark

estoy dando mis primeros pasos con pyspark. Realice la instalación de spark 3.1.1 y estoy intentando comenzar una sesión pero se genera el siguiente error:

```
import findspark
findspark.init ()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Invalid Spark URL: spark://HeartbeatReceiver@Fercho_PC:55980
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointAddress$.apply(RpcEndpointAddress.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.asyncSetupEndpointRefByURI(NettyRpcEnv.scala:140)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.util.RpcUtils$.makeDriverRef(RpcUtils.scala:36)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.(Executor.scala:218)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:220)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:579)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Por favor si saben que puede estar sucediendo?